# ACM bibtex format problem

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, acm

all, I am using ACM format (Strict Adherence to SIGS style) to edit my bibtex file. Now I have a strange problem, this is my code:

```
 @INCOLLECTION{Chen06
 AUTHOR = "Chen, Yi-Wei and Lin, Chih-Jen",
 TITLE = "Combining SVMs with Various Feature Selection Strategies",
 BOOKTITLE = {Feature Extraction},
 PUBLISHER = "Springer Berlin Heidelberg",
 PAGES = {315-324},
 YEAR={2006} }
```

Now when I BibTex it, I got the following error:

```
 I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 262 of file cikmRefs.bib
 : 
 : AUTHOR = "Chen, Yi-Wei and Lin, Chih-Jen",
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--empty author in Chen06
Warning--empty title in Chen06
Warning--empty booktitle in Chen06
Warning--empty publisher in Chen06
Warning--empty year in Chen06
```

I missed a comma after 'Chen06', thx guys. Another problem is that the compiler gave me the following error and corresponds to the following code:

```
 @INCOLLECTION{Platt99a,
 AUTHOR = "Platt, John C.",
 CHAPTER = "Fast training of support vector machines using sequential minimal optimization",
 BOOKTITLE = {Advances in kernel methods},
 PUBLISHER = "MIT Press",
 ADDRESS = "Cambridge, MA, USA",
 YEAR = {1999}  } 

 Warning--empty title in Platt99a
```

I can't find any problem with my code.

Comment: Do you need a comma after `Chen06`?

Comment: You need a comma at the end of `Chen06` :)

Comment: For an [@incollection entry](https://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-13.html) the *title* is mandatory. Change the field name from *chapter* to *title*.